# How do I use systemctl status httpd with -l, --full option. I cannot see the whole content of long lines in the output

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, journalctl

I want to check the status of `httpd` on my system.
I want to use it with `-l, --full` option, to see the whole contents of the long lines.

I've read it [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html), that there's option like `-l, --full` which will:

```
Do not ellipsize unit names, process tree entries, journal output, or truncate unit
descriptions in the output of status, list-units, list-jobs, and list-timers.  
Also, show installation targets in the output of is-enabled.
```

But no matter what I do, no matter where I put `-l, --full` option, my output lines get truncated like so:

```
Thu May 11 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ sudo systemctl status --full httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-11 07:55:18 CEST; 1min 48s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 2441 (httpd)
   Status: "Running, listening on: port 443, 10.32.81.217 port 80, ..."
    Tasks: 213 (limit: 10493)
   Memory: 27.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─2441 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2443 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2444 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2445 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─2446 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain httpd[2441]: Server configured, listening on: port 443, 10.32.81.217 port 80, ...
Thu May 11 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ sudo systemctl status -l httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-11 07:55:18 CEST; 19min ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 2441 (httpd)
   Status: "Running, listening on: port 443, 10.32.81.217 port 80, ..."
    Tasks: 213 (limit: 10493)
   Memory: 27.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─2441 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2443 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2444 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2445 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─2446 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain httpd[2441]: Server configured, listening on: port 443, 10.32.81.217 port 80, ...
Thu May 11 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ sudo systemctl -l status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-11 07:55:18 CEST; 19min ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 2441 (httpd)
   Status: "Running, listening on: port 443, 10.32.81.217 port 80, ..."
    Tasks: 213 (limit: 10493)
   Memory: 27.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─2441 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2443 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2444 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2445 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─2446 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain httpd[2441]: Server configured, listening on: port 443, 10.32.81.217 port 80, ...
Thu May 11 [michal@Ora1 ~]$ sudo systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-11 07:55:18 CEST; 20min ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 2441 (httpd)
   Status: "Running, listening on: port 443, 10.32.81.217 port 80, ..."
    Tasks: 213 (limit: 10493)
   Memory: 27.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─2441 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2443 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2444 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2445 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─2446 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
May 11 07:55:18 Ora1.localdomain httpd[2441]: Server configured, listening on: port 443, 10.32.81.217 port 80, ...
```

As you can see above, there is no real difference whether I use `-l, --full` option or not.

How to force systemctl, to display the whole contents of long lines in the output?

Comment: "How to force bash, to display the whole contents of long lines in the output?" – Bash neither displays nor relays output from executables. The executable (`systemctl` in your case) prints to the tty directly.